# Return multiple Arrays with different Values

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I return multiple Arrays with different Values? In my first function I get all files that are in my Folder.

In my second function I extract for each file the "modDesc.xml" and get my Information out of it. Now i want to return for each files a array with all this informations! But i dont know how.. I hope someone can help me!

Here is my code:

```
public string[] openDirectory(string DirectoryPath)
{
   string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath, "*.zip");

   return files;
}
```

```
public string[] getModDesc(string DirectoryPath)
{
    string[] files = openDirectory(DirectoryPath);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
        {
            ZipEntry modDescHandler = zip["modDesc.xml"];

            if (modDescHandler != null)
            {
                if (File.Exists("tmp\\modDesc.xml"))
                {
                    File.Delete("tmp\\modDesc.xml");
                }

                modDescHandler.Extract("tmp");

                XDocument modDesc = XDocument.Load("tmp\\modDesc.xml");
                string modTitle = null;
                string modAuthor = null;
                string modVersion = null;
                string modFileName = null;

                try
                {
                    modTitle = modDesc.Element("modDesc").Element("title").Element("de").Value;
                    modAuthor = modDesc.Element("modDesc").Element("author").Value;
                    modVersion = modDesc.Element("modDesc").Element("version").Value;
                }

                catch
                {

                }

                modFileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

                string[] modInformation = { modTitle, modAuthor, modVersion, modFileName };

                File.Delete("tmp\\modDesc.xml");

                return modInformation;

            }
        }
    }

    return new string[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a `List<string[]>` (i.e. a list of arrays) which would contain your collection of arrays for each file :

```
public List<string[]> getModDesc(string DirectoryPath)
{
       // Create a list to store your arrays
       List<string[]> fileInformation = new List<string[]>();

       // Get your files
       string[] files = openDirectory(DirectoryPath);
       foreach (var file in files)
       {
              using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
              {
                    // All your code (omitted for brevity)

                    // Create your array for this file
                    string[] modInformation = { modTitle, modAuthor, modVersion, modFileName }; 

                    // Add this to your list
                    fileInformation.Add(modInformation);
              }
        }
        // At this point your arrays collection should have all of your 
        // arrays, so return it
        return fileInformation;
    }
}
```

Or if your file names were each unique and you wanted to make accessing them a bit easier, you could store them in a Dictionary that would allow you to look each one up by it's name :

```
public Dictionary<string,string[]> getModDesc(string DirectoryPath)
{
   // Create a list to store your arrays
   Dictionary<string,string[]> fileInformation = new Dictionary<string,string[]>();

   // Get your files
   string[] files = openDirectory(DirectoryPath);
   foreach (var file in files)
   {
          using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
          {
                // All your code (omitted for brevity)

                // Create your array for this file
                string[] modInformation = { modTitle, modAuthor, modVersion, modFileName }; 

                // Add this to your dictionary, mapping the file name
                // to it's information
                fileInformation.Add(modFileName,modInformation);
          }
    }
    // At this point your dictionary should have all of your 
    // arrays, so return it
    return fileInformation;
}
```

}

Then, if you wanted to access the information from a file in your dictionary, you could simply use :

```
string[] information = yourDictionary["YourFileName"];
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it works.. :P How can I get the value from the list?

Comment: You could either iterate through it using a loop, or use `yourList.ElementAt(index)` to pull a specific index. Additionally, if you wanted to just return an array of arrays, you could change the return type of your method to `string[][]` and just change `return fileInformation` to `return fileInformation.ToArray()`, then you could reference you values by their index (like you would in any other array).

Comment: I have my foreach loop `foreach(var file in fileInformaton)` and now I want to get the information from the array to another list `var list = new Mod { isModEnabled = true, modTitle = file[][] };` How can I get them? Sorry I'm a beginner :]

Comment: If you are iterating through your `fileInformation` list /array, then `file` in the context of the loop will be your information for that file. So if you needed to access the `modTitle` property, you could just use `file[0]` as it was the first value you set in the array you created. `fileInformation` is a `string[][]` but when iterating through the individual items using a `foreach` loop, you are just working with `string[]` items.

Comment: Mhh.. My program should show me 3 folders, but it only show one.. Maybe my variable for the function is not right? `List<string[]> fileInformaton = fs.getModDesc(path)`

Comment: It looks right. Have you tried placing a breakpoint in your method and using the debugger to walk through it as it executes? You should have an array for each of the files in your directory.

Comment: It happens only one time.. Can you open a chat? I don't have so much reputation.

Comment: I did it. I returned the value of the `list<string[]>` in the `foreach` loop.. :P Im very thankful for your help!!